# Inspect data while debuging in java

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Suppose we are in a middle of debugging a application and you have a linkedlist, hashmap or other collection framework implementation with 1000 of items. Is there a possibility to inspect the list or map over a given item while debugging and not programmatically ? Suppose we are using eclipse as a ide.

Comment: While debugging, select the variable and press Ctrl+Shift+I, it's the same procedure for variables of any type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `Debug` perspective

[image]

There is `Variables` view , where you can see inner structure and elements of every object in current context.

[image]

In `Expressions` view you can add custom one-line expression to get any result.

[image]

Maybe, `Display` view will be useful, where you can execute set of Java expressions.

[image]